# Does the order of EF linq query clauses influence performance?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Should I worry about the order of Entity Framework linq query clauses in terms of performance?

In the example below could changing the order of the two where clauses have an performance impact on the DB lookup?

```
        using (var context = new ModelContext())
        {
            var fetchedImages = (from images in context.Images.Include("ImageSource")
                                 where images.Type.Equals("jpg")
                                 where images.ImageSource.Id == 5
                                 select images).ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Check the generated SQL with both Where and a single condition with `&&`, if they are same then there shouldn't be any difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, changing of these two `where` clauses will not affect performance. 
Generated SQL will look like this anyway:

```
WHERE [condition1] AND [condition2]
```

Besides, you can write conditions, combined with logical operators:

```
where images.Type.Equals("jpg") && images.ImageSource.Id == 5
```

Comment: That's only if you ignore short circuiting: if `[condition2]` is false more often than `[condition1]`, you might see a performance gain by swapping the order.

Comment: @RoadieRich: although you're right in theory, do you really believe, that you might **see** any difference, when swapping these two conditions? :)

Comment: Given an appropriately large dataset, yes you might.

Comment: @RoadieRich: could you post any public available test results? I'll explain my sarcasm: any I/O operation at RDBMS-side spends more than several orders higher time, that comparing two string or int values. This difference should kill your optimization easily.

Comment: @RoadieRich No short circuiting here. The whole expression is translated into SQL. The database engine is the first thing to look into optimizations. It will order the predicates as it deems best.

Answer (score -1):

The general case is that the `where` operators will "short circuit", so if the first is false, the second won't even be examined, so if one will fail more frequently, generally you want to check it first.

However, this breaks down if the more frequent failure is slow to process.

**The only way to tell for sure is by profiling your code using appropriate tools.**

Comment: While true for LINQ-to-Objects, he specifically states "have an performance impact on the DB lookup" where this answer does not apply. Once it gets translated to SQL, the db provider will decide what to do with it (as Gert Arnold stated in the other answer).